# Why it it possible to replace these types?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Some thing seems to be incredible:

`foo :: a -> StateT Env (ReaderT Env (ErrorT String IO)) String`

may be replaced with
`foo :: a -> ErrorT String IO String`

How is it possible ?  After all, they are absolutely different types...

Comment: In general, it's due to polymorphism and overloading. It's not possible to say exactly without seeing the code for `foo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly, it is not possible to replace these with one another in *all* circumstances. For instance, if you explicitly use `ErrorT . return $ Left "Muahar"`, then this *must* be an `ErrorT String m a`.

However, both types are of the form `a -> M String`, with a (transformer-stack) monad `M` which is an instance of [`MonadIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t:MonadIO) and [`MonadError String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#t:MonadError). So, if this function is defined using only actions of the form `liftIO ioaction`, and possibly `throwError` and `catchError`, then it'll work as any of these monads. The general type is

```
foo :: (MonadIO m, MonadError String m) => a -> m String
```

Comment: If you remove your own type signature from `foo` and then use `:t foo` in ghci you can see the most general type that `foo` can have, which is often quite helpful. Also `:i SomeFunctionOrTypeOrTypeClass` can be very useful when figuring out monad stacks.

Comment: Right, though this should not be seen as an invitation to ever omit type signatures in code that's actually supposed to be _used_.

Comment: Also, sometimes the inferred type shown by ghci is not really the most useful one – or would you like documentation that says `smoothInterpolate
  :: (Data.LinearMap.HerMetric.HasMetric' y,
      Data.LinearMap.HerMetric.HasMetric' (Data.LinearMap.HerMetric.DualSpace y,
        ` ...(more constraints)... `Data.LinearMap.HerMetric.DualSpace
        (Data.LinearMap.HerMetric.DualSpace y)
      ~ y, Scalar (Needly y) ~ manifolds-0.2.1.0:Data.Manifold.Types.Primitive.ℝ) =>
     Data.List.NonEmpty.NonEmpty (x, y) -> x -> y`?

Comment: So it will be ok (when it comes to types) when from function I return something like `m a`

Comment: Well, not _anything_ like `m a`. It does need to be a monad fulfilling the necessary constraints.